# Anti-Twin's Byte by Byte" vs. "Compare images (pixels)"

Tags: deduplication, pixels

Kindly see the [red rectangle below](http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/). How does "Byte by Byte" differ from "Compare images (pixels)"? Which is more accurate? What are the pros and cons of each?

[image: Screenshot]

Advise me if I got to ask this separately, but [how does a byte relate to a pixel](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relationship-between-bytes-and-pixels)? I can't decide which answer on Quora is correct.

Comment: my guess is for byteXbyte, they hash the file and if the hashes equal, they are the same. The same image however can be encoded in many ways. Jpeg has 29 levels of compression, so the same image may have a different hash, but when rendered, all of its pixels have the same value, so its the same image.

Comment: @FrankThomas Can you please explain that like I'm 5? Your comment is too complicated for me!

Comment: hmmm. ok so computer raster image formats specify the color of each pixel. that way when the file is read and processed, the image is just presented as a grid of pixels of the right color to show the image. Bitmaps are some of the oldest formats, and are literally stored as color codes for each pixel. so comparing a pair of identical bitmaps, the bytes of the image file will be exactly the same. if one starts with 0xFFBB00, and the other starts with 0xFFBB01, then those two images are not identical. the first pixel (top left I believe) is slightly different in color.

Comment: for bitmap, since it only uses 256 colors, it always uses 1 byte to store one pixel. compressed images like jpegs and pngs however seek to store the images data in less than the number of bytes that it has pixels. for instance a bitmap at 1024x768 resolution will always be 786KB (unless color dithering is used, but I'm not going to explain that). jpeg format could store that same image, with a higher number of colors (65536, 4294967296, etc), in fewer bytes, because it has been compressed.

Comment: compression changes the what the bytes in the file mean, so that you could have two files with different binary/bytes, but that when processed yield the same set of pixels so they are the same image, but the files are different. so if you have two versions of the same image with different levels or types of compression, they would not be detected as duplicates if you used byte-by-byte, but would be detected if you compared by pixels.